# Updating dynamic select drop down value from a hash

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a large hash like this which has makes and models of vehicles:

> makes_models = {"AM General":["Hummer"], "Acura":["CL", "ILX", "ILX
>   Hybrid", "Integra", "Legend", "MDX", "NSX", "RDX", "RL", "RLX", "RSX",
>   "SLX", "TL", "TLX", "TSX", "TSX Sport Wagon", "Vigor", "ZDX"], "Alfa
>   Romeo":["4C"], "Aston Martin":["DB7", "DB9", "DBS", "Rapide", "Rapide
>   S", "V12 Vanquish", "V12 Vantage", "V8 Vantage", "Vanquish",
>   "Virage"], "Audi":["100", "200", "80", "90", "A3", "A3 e-tron", "A4",
>   "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8", "Cabriolet", "Coupe", "Q1", "Q3", "Q5", "Q7",
>   "R8", "RS 4", "RS 5", "RS 6", "RS 7", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S6", "S7",
>   "S8", "SQ5", "TT", "TT RS", "TTS", "V8", "allroad", "allroad
>   quattro"]}

I have a select which lets you select the hash key of the model:

```
<%= vehicle.select(:make, options_for_select(["AM General", "Acura", ...] )) %>
```

I have jQuery to update the model select based on the make selected:

```
$('select#quote_vehicles_make').change(function() {
    $.each(models[$(this).val()], function( idx, value ) {
      $('select#quote_vehicles_models').html("<option>" + value + "</option>");
    });
});
```

Model select:

```
<select id="quote_vehicles_models">
  <option>...</option>
</select>
```

Problem is that the select is only returning the last value in the `makes_models` hash. So If for example I select: **Acura**, then the models select updates and only shows: **ZDX**

[image: screenshot]

1. How do I fix this jQuery?
2. Is their a simple rails/jQuery solution for generating dynamic select boxes from a hash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem: jQuery:

```
$('select#quote_vehicles_make').change(function() {
  $('select#quote_vehicles_models').empty();
    $.each(models[$(this).val()], function( idx, value ) {
      $('select#quote_vehicles_models').append("<option>" + value + "</option>");
    });
});
```

Still interested in a Rails oriented solution if one exists. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

consider data structures here:

```
def make
     {"AM General":["Hummer"], "Acura":["CL", "ILX", "ILX Hybrid", "Integra", "Legend", "MDX",
        "NSX", "RDX", "RL", "RLX", "RSX", "SLX", "TL", "TLX", "TSX", "TSX Sport Wagon", "Vigor", "
        ZDX"], "Alfa Romeo":["4C"], "Aston Martin":["DB7", "DB9", "DBS", "Rapide", "Rapide S", "V12
        Vanquish", "V12 Vantage", "V8 Vantage", "Vanquish", "Virage"], "Audi":["100", "200", "80", 
        "90", "A3", "A3 e-tron", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8", "Cabriolet", "Coupe", "Q1", "Q3", 
        "Q5", "Q7", "R8", "RS 4", "RS 5", "RS 6", "RS 7", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S6", "S7", "S8", "SQ5",
        "TT", "TT RS", "TTS", "V8", "allroad", "allroad quattro"]}[model]
end
```

then you can make a list of models for each vehicle like:

```
make[@vehicle.model]
```

you can do this with jquery too, just define the make function as a javascript function, get the selected model, and pass it to the make function. the output will be an array of makes for that model, which you can then pass in as html options for the next select box.